# Function in excel to change row BackColor to grey if A1 value + B1 value = C1 value

Tags: excel, vba

I want help in VBA Function in excel to change row BackColor to grey if A1 value + D1 value = C1 value

and change it to red if A1 value + D1 value = 0.9*C1 Value

I want it like this code it is work very well

```
Function CountCellsByColor(rData As Range, cellRefColor As Range) As Long
    Dim indRefColor As Long
    Dim cellCurrent As Range
    Dim cntRes As Long

    Application.Volatile 
    cntRes = 0
    indRefColor = cellRefColor.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
    For Each cellCurrent In rData
        If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Interior.Color Then
            cntRes = cntRes + 1
        End If
    Next cellCurrent
    CountCellsByColor = cntRes
End Function
```

Comment: Why don't you try writing something yourself? All you've done here is ask for code and post a mostly-unrelated function.  Post back with your effort and describe any problems you ran into.

Comment: @TimWilliams I can't access Excel now to try because I am traveled for Business trip after back from trip my time for testing code is so short , so I want to get some code to save my time .. I hope you to help me

Comment: @pnuts How ?? VBA is a choice not a coerce

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your code, what you have to do is something like.

```
 if range("a1").value + range("d1").value = range("c1").value then
  Range('"the row you want to change"').interior.color= 'lookforgreycolorrgb'
 else if range("a1").value + range("d1").value = (.9*range("c1").value) then
  Range('"the row you want to change"').interior.color= vbRed
 end if
```

It is just an example/guide of what you must do. Hope it helps